# ContinueWith as an alternative to the await operator

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lua, task

My application uses scripts. So far, I've used C# for the scripts and compiled them using the `CodeDomProvider`. However, I've been thinking about switching to Lua using the `NLua` fork (a fork of the `LuaInterface`) because it's much easier to write scripts with plus I'm familiar with the syntax.

However, I'm facing a problem. Currently, I have an `asynchronous` method that returns a `Task<bool>`. It uses a `TaskCompletionSource` object and returns it's `Result`. That way, I can halt the execution of the script because it waits until the `Result` of the `TaskCompletionSource` object has been set, and only then returns this `Result`.

Now, with Lua - it's different. I obviously can't use the `await`operator because it's a syntax of C# 5.0, and you can't use that in Lua. So that's why I'm asking if there's a workaround for this. I want to be able to achieve the same result as my old code (which is posted beneath this post) without having to use the `await`operator. I've been told that I can do that with `Task.ContinueWith`, but I'm unfamiliar with this and the examples online are dull. If anyone can show me an example with my code, it'd be great.

Here's my method:

```
public async Task<bool> ReturnResult()
{
     this.Response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

     return await this.Response.Task;
}
```

Here's the way I'm using it in my scripts:

```
var result = await ReturnResult();
```

The `Result` of the `TaskCompletionSource` object is set by another part of my code.

Basically, if you still failed to understand what I want to achieve - a method that halts it's execution until a response has been set by another part of the code. However, it has to be `asynchronous`, because I don't want my main thread to get stuck.

**EDIT:** Tried JonSkeet's suggestion and the code just runs without halting. Here's the full Script class.

```
public class Script
{
    private Lua Lua { get; set; }
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> Response { get; set; }

    public Script()
    {
        this.Lua = new Lua();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        this.Lua.RegisterFunction("log", this, typeof(Script).GetMethod("Log"));
        this.Lua.RegisterFunction("returnResult", this, typeof(Script).GetMethod("ReturnResult"));

        this.Lua.DoFile(@"C:\test.lua");
    }

    public void SetResponse(bool response)
    {
        this.Response.SetResult(response);
    }

    public Task<bool> ReturnResult()
    {
        this.Response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        return this.Response.Task;
    }

    public void Log(string text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}
```

Here's the code of Form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Script Script { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Script = new Script();

        this.Script.Run();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Script.SetResponse(true);
    }
}
```

Just throw two buttons and use the first one to run, second one to set response.

The Lua script is:

```
result = returnResult()
log("returned " .. result)
```

Download [NLua](https://github.com/NLua/NLua) from here.

Comment: Can you use `Task` and `ContinueWith` in your Lua script? Also, could you add the other part of your code which sets the result?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, but I can register a method that involves those to use in my Lua script. The Lua script can't involve C# syntax.

Comment: Why are you using an async method at all? Why aren't you just returning `this.Response.Task`? Awaiting it doesn't help. To be honest, your question really isn't clear...

Comment: I am a bit confused why you're using `TaskCompletionSource` at all

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Because I'm not familiar with Tasks, really. I just want to be able to halt the exceution of the script without halting the main thread and then return a response (only once it's been set by another part of my code). If I don't use the await operator - the code will just continue to run.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I don't use the await operator my code will just continue to run.

Comment: The async method will return anyway. Honestly, returning the task for the TCS is going to be near-equivalent, and simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please refer to the main post, I updated a sample program so you can see what I'm trying to achieve. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. The first button runs the script, the second button sets the result. It should halt itself until I press the second button.

Comment: @user3865229: Well you still need to await the result of `ReturnResult`. Currently in your Lua script you're *ignoring* the return value entirely. I was *only* suggesting a change in the `ReturnResult` method, which is pointlessly `async`.

Comment: @JonSkeet The problem is that you can't use C# syntax in Lua. That's why I asked for a solution that doesn't use the await operator - which  can be done, according to some people, with ContinueWith.

Comment: @user3865229: Yes, and that's fine. *All* I was doing was pointing out that your `ReturnResult` method could be simplified. I suggest you go back to the "dull" examples you've found - dull or not, they should show you what you need to do. (We only have a *tiny* bit of your Lua script, so we don't really know what else you're doing.)

Comment: @JonSkeet That's fine, but still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: And that's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you try and answer, possibly, or give me an antlernative solution that maybe doesn't use tasks?

Comment: No, as I don't know Lua and don't intend to learn it for the sake of one SO question. Again, it sounds like you've found resources which will help you - the fact that you find them "dull" doesn't mean they won't be useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet Giving me a solution for what I'm trying to achieve has nothing to do with Lua. Imagine a Form with 2 buttons. You want one button to call a method that returns a bool, but you want it to not return anything until the second button sets the response that it needs to return. THAT'S what I'm trying to achieve. No Lua involved.

Comment: You've misunderstood asynchrony. It's not that the method doesn't return - it's that the method returns almost immediately, but then calls some *other* code when it's finished its job. That code is what you put in the `ContinueWith`. (Maybe that code is the logging code in your example. I don't know.) I can give you the C# code that would just log, using ContinueWith, but I can't give it to you in Lua.

Comment: @JonSkeet Again, it has NOTHING to do with Lua. If you can, show me  an example with ContinueWith.

Comment: So now I've given an answer... is it what you were looking for, or not? I was expecting at least some feedback...

Answer (score 5):

Okay, as you now claim this has nothing to do with Lua, here's how you would call the method in C#, then log only when the task had completed:

```
Task<bool> task = ReturnResult();
task.ContinueWith(t => Log("Returned " + t.Result));
```

This does *not* halt execution at all - it just says that when the task returned from `ReturnResult` completes, it should call the logging code.

For production code, you would probably want to check whether the task was faulted, etc. There are overloads of `ContinueWith` which allow you to specify under which circumstances you want to run the continuation (only on success, only on fault etc), and you can add multiple continuations. But to get you going, the above is probably good enough.